# How to create OpenSSH private key with password using java BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openssh

Simple way to create OpenSSH keys with non password encrypted private key:

```
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator gen = new Ed25519KeyPairGenerator();
    gen.init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 255));
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = gen.generateKeyPair();
    byte[] bprv = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(kp.getPrivate());
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PemWriter w = new PemWriter(sw);
    w.writeObject(new PemObject("OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", bprv)); w.close();
    String privateKey = sw.toString(); sw.close();
    System.out.println(privateKey);
    byte[] bpub = OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.encodePublicKey(kp.getPublic());
    sw = new StringWriter();
    w = new PemWriter(sw);
    w.writeObject(new PemObject("SSH2 PUBLIC KEY", bpub)); w.close();
    String publicKey = sw.toString(); sw.close();
```

But how to create private key encrypted with password? Is it possible?

Comment: I suspect that this is not possible out-of-the-box even with BouncyCastle. You will probably have to implement this yourself, analogous to the non-encrypted key code (see [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.java#L101)). Are you limited to BouncyCastle, or can you also use other libraries (there are libraries that can generate encrypted OpenSSH keys)?

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for your reply. You've given me some ideas. I found a resource describing [SSH key formats](https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2021/06/03/public-key-cryptography-openssh-private-keys/) in sufficient detail. Probably on the basis of this information I will be able to write my own library. I'm not limited to BouncyCastle, it's just that I don't know anything else.

Comment: If you can't find a solution with BC or it's too elaborate, and since you're not restricted to BC, I'll post a solution with the *maverick-synergy* library, which can be used to create encrypted OpenSSH keys relatively easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a way to export encrypted OpenSSH keys with BouncyCastle: A library that allows exporting encrypted OpenSSH keys out-of-the-box is [sshtools/maverick-synergy](https://github.com/sshtools/maverick-synergy).

Example of generating an Ed25519 key pair with export of the private encrypted key and the public key:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

import com.sshtools.common.publickey.SshKeyUtils;
import com.sshtools.common.ssh.components.SshKeyPair;
import com.sshtools.common.ssh.components.jce.JCEAlgorithms;
import com.sshtools.common.ssh.components.jce.SshEd25519PrivateKeyJCE;
import com.sshtools.common.ssh.components.jce.SshEd25519PublicKeyJCE;

...

// Create Ed25519 key pair
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(JCEAlgorithms.ED25519);
KeyPair kp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
SshKeyPair pair = new SshKeyPair();
pair.setPrivateKey(new SshEd25519PrivateKeyJCE(kp.getPrivate()));
pair.setPublicKey(new SshEd25519PublicKeyJCE(kp.getPublic()));

// Export
System.out.println(SshKeyUtils.getFormattedKey(pair, "my passphrase"));
System.out.println(SshKeyUtils.getFormattedKey(pair.getPublicKey(), "my comment"));
```

with the following sample output:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDN
3FuF2G77g48ktctKG3NTAAAAEAAAAAEAAAAzAAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIO+e
PM91Qbd6b6bF8sKfOJiox19K1llf8UwUbUayPmRHAAAAkD7rMYeeAKeyiwEU1uy2
iNsXTTWHR2jK2abcQ3Qndw1lQBmM+QfmdefnoN4HToSuSVzybaLBRoHl5vybFq74
5JaZ9ZQitXBrBLX91imjGmHDPr/nOYWo57Yuh05gPnx96MZHo61Ze6HNWhZ73xBT
6ve7YAxCDO8LjGjyC17k2/0HMcPOwbV8J39f5KTeXNf6vA==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIO+ePM91Qbd6b6bF8sKfOJiox19K1llf8UwUbUayPmRH my comment
```

---

The format of the OpenSSH private key is described e.g. [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/) (and in more detail, especially concerning the encryption logic, [here](https://dnaeon.github.io/openssh-private-key-binary-format/)). If the encrypted OpenSSH private key is Base64 decoded, the individual parts can be identified:

```
6f70656e7373682d6b65792d763100                              "openssh-key-v1" + 0x00
0000000a 6165733235362d637472                               length: 0x0a, "aes256-ctr"
00000006 626372797074                                       length: 0x06, "bcrypt"
00000018 00000010cddc5b85d86efb838f24b5cb4a1b735300000010   total length: 0x18, salt length: 0x10 + <salt, here 0xcddc5b85d86efb838f24b5cb4a1b7353> + <rounds, here 0x10>
00000001 
00000033 0000000b7373682d6564323535313900000020ef9e3ccf7541b77a6fa6c5f2c29f3898a8c75f4ad6595ff14c146d46b23e6447
00000090 3eeb31879e00a7b28b0114d6ecb688db174d35874768cad9a6dc437427770d6540198cf907e675e7e7a0de074e84ae495cf26da2c14681e5e6fc9b16aef8e49699f59422b5706b04b5fdd629a31a61c33ebfe73985a8e7b62e874e603e7c7de8c647a3ad597ba1cd5a167bdf1053eaf7bb600c420cef0b8c68f20b5ee4dbfd0731c3cec1b57c277f5fe4a4de5cd7fabc
```

The second line contains a description of the encryption algorithm, the third a description of the key derivation function (KDF) used, and the fourth a description of the KDF options.
In the case of an *un*encrypted key, the lines for algorithm and KDF are each *0x000000046e6f6e65* (i.e. length: 0x04 + "none") and the line with the KDF options is *0x00000000* (i.e. length: 0).
For the generated key these values are different and show that the key is encrypted with AES-256 in CTR mode and *bcrypt* (more precisely, an OpenSSH specific variant of *bcrypt*) is applied as KDF.